# Programming software for Boefeng UV-5RE Plus

Tags: uv-5r

Which PC or Linux software would I use for programming a Boefeng UV-5RE Plus?

How would I make a programming cable to connect to USB/Serial conversion board (ebay FTDI board, size of finger)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use chirp ([http://chirp.danplanet.com](http://chirp.danplanet.com/)) to program it's memories. A simple USB-UART chip like this

[image]

..is all that I use to connect to the pc.

With regards to pinouts, use:

[image]

The above schematic shows connectivity for the UV-5R and the UV-3R. You can safely leave out the UV-3R stuff..

Courtesy of: http://www.uv3r.com/uv5r.html

Answer (score 0):

Not to mention that Baofeng more often than not includes a perfectly good FTDI USB data cable with the various UV-5Rs. A lot more handy than a serial adapter that is fragile. I use Chirp as well.

Comment: Please don't post what should be a comment as an answer instead.  We know you need 50 reputation points to comment, so please just wait until then before commenting.